# initialize base class whose constructor takes an reference

Tags: c++, c++11

I got the following error when I initialize the base class whose constructor takes a reference with a temporary object (`jsonrpc::HttpServer(port)`). I thought `std::move` is for this scenario but `std::move(jsonrpc::HttpServer(port)` doesn't work either. Any idea?

```
class Server : public jsonrpc::AbstractServer<Server>
{
    public:
        Server(jsonrpc::AbstractServerConnector &conn) : jsonrpc::AbstractServer<Server>(conn)
        {
            //...
        }
};

class MyServer: public Server {
    public: MyServer(int port);
}

// error
MyServer::EnclaveRPC(int port):Server(jsonrpc::HttpServer(port)){}
MyServer::EnclaveRPC(int port):Server(std::move(jsonrpc::HttpServer(port))){}
```

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘jsonrpc::AbstractServerConnector&’ from an rvalue of type ‘jsonrpc::AbstractServerConnector’
>    : Server(jsonrpc::HttpServer(port)){

Comment: Copy&paste the complete error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MyServer::EnclaveRPC(int port):Server(jsonrpc::HttpServer(port)){}
```

here you create a temporary object of type `jsonrpc::HttpServer` (rvalue) and try to pass it as an lvalue reference, which is prohibited for a good reason. `jsonrpc::AbstractServer` can store it as a member (most probably it does) to use it later, but the temp object will be deleted before executing the next line of you program

P.S.

`jsonrpc` library provides a weak interface of `jsonrpc::AbstractServer`. It should take ownership of a connection (e.g. by `std::unique_ptr`) or at least shared ownership by `std::shared_ptr`

Answer (score 2):

Your class is not the owner of the `jsonrpc::AbstractServerConnector`, since a reference does not carry ownership.

In that matter, you must have it sent to you, since the owner is external:

```
struct Server : jsonrpc::AbstractServer<Server>
{
        Server(jsonrpc::AbstractServerConnector& conn) : jsonrpc::AbstractServer<Server>(conn)
        {
            //...
        }
};

struct MyServer : Server {
    MyServer(jsonrpc::AbstractServerConnector& conn) : Server{conn} {}
};
```

This is probably what you need.

---

However, If you insist at being the owner of the resource, you can create a owning class that would be your first parent:

```
struct HttpConnectionOwner {
    explicit HttpConnectionOwner(int port) : conn{port} {}

    jsonrpc::HttpServer conn;
};

struct MyServer : HttpConnectionOwner, Server {
    explicit MyServer(int port) : HttpConnectionOwner{port}, Server{conn} {}
};
```

Also, if you have many connection type, you can make your class choose which type of connection you need:

```
template<typename ConnectionType>
struct MyServer : ConnectionType, Server {
    using ConnectionType::conn; // conn is now a dependent name

    explicit MyServer(int port) : ConnectionType{port}, Server{conn} {}
};

using MyHttpServer = MyServer<HttpConnectionOwner>;
using MyWebSocketServer = MyServer<WebSocketConnectionOwner>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always just take a pointer, but to be 100% safe, make it a `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` like this:

```
class testTempUnique {
public:
  testTempUnique(unique_ptr<int> &inPtr)
    : myPtr{ std::move(inPtr) } { }

  unique_ptr<int> myPtr;
};
auto mygeneratedClass = testTempUnique(make_unique<int>(5));
cout << "value inside is: " << *(mygeneratedClass.myPtr) << endl;
```

I have an `int` there but you get the idea.  And if you want to make it so the object can be "valid" other places, use a `shared_ptr<T>` instead.